# Why is Muruga also known as Thanikachalan?

Tags: name, kartikeya, skanda-purana

What is the meaning of Thanikachalan which the name of Lord Muruga?

Comment: Thanikachalam or Thiruthani is one of the six holy abodes of Lord Muruga in Tamilnadu. So Thanikachalan is "The Lord of Thanigai Hill."

Comment: @Surya you can add that as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's an ancient name **'Thanikachalam'**. It generally means Lord Muruga for his outstandingly handsome and robust, very masculine. He probably known as **'Kumaran'** an young boy.